# How to update Datatable selected rows in JSF using Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

Well though this question is duplicated somewhat, I have searched over the net still couldn't find the exact result what i want. In my case im developing a project in JSF using Primefaces which has CRUD functionality. i have more than 3k records in `p:dataTable`. If i want to update selected 5 records, i can only update the whole dataTable(takes much time).

**Scenario:**

1) select the records in Datatable
2) click `p:commandButton` to perform business logic and will provide the result for selected records.
(In `p:commandButton` i used datatable updation)

Note:
I can only forced to use `Primefaces`. (I found `omniFaces` has the solution but i shouldn't use)

Pls help me out!

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces will allow you to update component based on `styleClass`, using PrimeFacesSelectors(PFS).

`update="@(.mystyle)"`

You can use this to serve your purpose of updating particular row of datatable.
Here is the strategy:
1. Set unique `rowKey` as `styleClass` to each of columns for every row.
2. Use that `rowKey` at PFS for your `update` attribute.

Here is a short code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable var="mov" value="#{repeatUIBean.mList}" ro>
    <p:column headerText="mov Name">
        <h:outputText styleClass="#{mov.uniqueId}" value="#{mov.name}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="mov Release Year">
        <h:outputText styleClass="#{mov.uniqueId}" value="#{mov.year}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Edit mov">
        <p:commandButton value="Edit" update="@(.#{mov.uniqueId})"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: i have 30 columns, so i need to write uniquieid for all the columns. can you pls elaborate.

Comment: `uniqueId` does not need to be a separate property on your java Bean which you are loading on the datatable. Just choose one which is close to Unique in your bean [Plus, hey its always a pretty good idea to have a unique filed on a java bean]. IF anything you choose is repeated in another bean then it will update those ROWs as well. For example in my example if I choose `#{mov.name}` if there is another row with same movie name then it will update 2 rows. I would still use it because its better to update few rows than entire datatable.

Comment: in my case i need to update the selected rows using command button. I select the rows and click command button to refresh the rows.